# Appending to a list extracted through pop() also appends to the list element was popped from

Tags: python

I'm trying to practice pathfinding in python. I tried to extract the nodes from the pathlist using `pop()` and append their neighbors in the extracted list and append them back to the pathlist. My problem is when I append to `extr`, path somehow changes too.

```
path = [raw_input()]
extr = [path.pop()]
path.append(extr)
extr.append("abc1")
print extr
print path

input: abc
output: ['abc', 'abc1']
        [['abc', 'abc1']
expected output: ['abc', 'abc1']
                 [['abc'],['abc','abc1']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) that Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. , you can get the entry with indexing :

```
>>> extr = [path[0]]
>>> path.append(extr)
>>> extr.append("abc1")
>>> print extr
['abc', 'abc1']
>>> print path
['abc', ['abc', 'abc1']]
```

Comment: Thanks! But i forgot to say something. When i do this in a loop, the second elements and so on do the same problem. Perhaps a code without .append() would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You made a refrence of `extr` in `path` so when you change `extr` `(mutable object)` it will change `path` too.

```
path = [raw_input()]
extr = []
path.append(extr)
print path
extr.append("abc1")
print extr
print path
```

output:-

```
abc
['abc', []]
['abc1']
['abc', ['abc1']]
>>>
```